# When I use getSymbol() with periodicity = "weekly", the date are incorrect

Tags: r, quantmod

Here is my code, and I want to show the data as weekly.
The first data show the date as 2012-09-02, but that date is Sunday which is not a trading day.
How to show the first date as 2012-09-03?

```r
tickers <- c("0011.HK", "1299.HK", "1083.HK", "0823.HK", "0669.HK", "0992.HK")

portfolioPrices <- NULL
for (Ticker in tickers)
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                           getSymbols(Ticker, from = "2012-09-01", 
                                      to = "2022-08-31", 
                                      periodicity = "weekly", 
                                      auto.assign=FALSE)[, 4])
colnames(portfolioPrices) <- c("HSBC", "AIA", "TG", "LinkReit", "Techronic", "Lenovo")
portfolioPrices
```

The output shown as here:

[image: data]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/394). Converting the raw timestamps from Yahoo didn't account for the exchange timezone. This is fixed in quantmod version > 0.4.24.